# Powershell: how to call a function from inside of a foreach loop?

Tags: function, foreach, powershell-5.0

I'm testing if I can invoke a certain function based on the condition within a `foreach` loop:

```
$BROKER = $args[0]    
$MARKETS = $args[1], $args[2], $args[3], $args[4], $args[5], $args[6]


foreach ($market in $MARKETS) {
    if ($market -like 'all') {
        &AllMarkets
        break
    }
    else {
        &CertainMarkets
    }
}


function AllMarkets {
    "Checking all markets"
}


function CertainMarkets {
    "Checking certain markets"
}
```

When I run the script like this:

```
.\script.ps1 broker all
```

I get this error:

```
& : The term 'AllMarkets' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
```

How to call these functions from inside the foreach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function AllMarkets {
    "Checking all markets"
}


function CertainMarkets {
    "Checking certain markets"
}
$BROKER = $args[0]    
$MARKETS = $args[1], $args[2], $args[3], $args[4], $args[5], $args[6]


foreach ($market in $MARKETS) {
    if ($market -like 'all') {
        &AllMarkets
        break
    }
    else {
        &CertainMarkets
    }
}
```

The functions should be defined before the loop. Otherwise, the functions are not yet visible.